# how to send image from whatsapp C# api

Tags: c#, image, api, whatsapp

I am not getting how to send image to any number using WhatsApiNet ?

```
case "/image":
byte[] imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\My Creations\DSC_0423 copy.jpg");
wa.SendMessageImage(tmpUser.GetFullJid(), imgData, ApiBase.ImageType.JPEG);
break;!
```

But its not working..

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an exception? If so, show the exception details.

Comment: there is no exception occurred. but at same time image also not sent. and application get hang.

Comment: i got error : BinTreeNodeReader->readListSize: Invalid token 24

Answer (score 1):

I too was facing the same problem, fortunately I got the solution :)

```
byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes("e:\\img.gif");
wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
{
      MessageBox.Show("Connected to whatsapp...");

      wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
      {
          wa.SendMessage(to, msg);

          wa.SendMessageImage(to + "@s.whatsapp.net",img,ApiBase.ImageType.GIF);
          MessageBox.Show("Message Sent...");
      };
}
```

You will just need to modify only 1 line in your code.

```
wa.SendMessageImage(tmpUser.GetFullJid()+ "@s.whatsapp.net", imgData, ApiBase.ImageType.JPEG);
```

Hop this will help others too :D Hav a Nyc day :)

Answer (score 0):

See: [Is it legal to use WhatsAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520776/is-it-legal-to-use-whatsapi)

There seems to be an indication of ongoing legal issues between WhatsApp and the creator of the API open-source project.

There's also mention that WhatsApp have changed some of the details around authentication, so it may be the case that you can't send the message simply because WhatsApp have stopped allowing access.

Comment: No it is not illegal. there is no law which indicate it is illegal.and i am not try to do this for any marketing tool or sale it. and there are many apps which are working till now.

Comment: @user3783206 I'm not saying it's illegal, simply that there is ongoing legal dispute between WhatsApp and users of the API, mostly owing to spam being sent over the network.

Comment: yes whats app take step for stopping this spams now when you get whats app message from unknown no you can register no as spam.you are right...